# toggling html values

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Toggle button and Toggle visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652119/toggle-button-and-toggle-visibility)

I have a piece of text on a page which acts as a button,

```
<span class="button">Show Activities</span>
```

When you click it it hides or shows some html.  I want to change the html of it so I tried this

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.overview').slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).html("<span>Hide activities</span>")
});
```

It changes the text of the html, but I want it to change back when I click it again.  Is there a function like toggle but for putting html back to the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var text = $(this).text() == 'Show Activities' ? 'Hide Activities' : 'Show Activities';
$(this).html(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the selector you are thinking of is the "innerHTML" of the span, which you could change in javascript once you are finished showing the text, so that "Show Activities" changes to "Hide Activities", and then just write up a little function that does the exact opposite of your "Show Activities" code. :)

```
<span class="button" id="hideShow">Show Activities</span>
```

And then in your javascript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('hideShow');
elem.innerHTML = "Hide Activities";
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this can help you

http://www.wikihow.com/Toggle-HTML-Display-With-JavaScript

```
var textHidden = true;
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(textHidden) {
    ele.style.display = "inline";
    text.innerHTML = "Show";
    textHidden = false

}
else {
    textHidden = true
    ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "Hide";

}
}​
```

html

```
<a id="displayText" href="#" onclick="toggle();">Show Further Details Specification</a>    
<div id="toggleText" style="display:none;"><h1>peek-a-boo</h1></div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `text()` method:

```
$(this).text(
    function(i,t) {
        return t.indexOf('Hide') !== -1 ? 'Show activities' : 'Hide activities';
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7N2qH/1/).

Also, cache your `$(this)` object to reduce the DOM traversal *each time you call `$(this)`*:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.siblings('.overview').slideToggle('slow');
    that.text(function(i, t) {
        return t.indexOf('Hide') !== -1 ? 'Show activities' : 'Hide activities';
    });
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7N2qH/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=false;

$('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.overview').slideToggle('slow');
    if(!a){
    $(this).html("Hide activities");
    a=true;
    }
else
{
$(this).html("Show activities");
    a=false;
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out!...

> $('.button').click(function() {
>
> ```
> $(this).siblings('.overview').slideToggle('slow');
>
> if($(this).text() == 'Show Activities')
>     $(this).text('Hide Activities');
> else
>     $(this).text('Show Activities');
> ```
>
> });